# mvc 4 bundle - jQuery not showing up first even tho I added it first

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**global.asax:**

```
var desktopJsBundle = new Bundle("~/desktop-js-bundle", new JsMinify());
desktopJsBundle.AddFile("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js");
desktopJsBundle.AddFile("~/scripts/test.js");
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(desktopJsBundle);
```

**layout.cshtml:**

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/desktop-js-bundle")"></script>
```

If I visit `localhost/desktop-js-bundle/`, I see similar to the following:

```
/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
function mytest(){alert('test');}(function(a,b){function cy(a){return f............
```

As you can see, it started with the comment that is found at top of jquery.js file, then there is the content from my test.js file, then back to the content of jquery.js file. Odd behavior.  Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some internal Ordering going on, it is following certain rules, you can override those rules though.

Here is how you specify the exact order of files:

```
 //controls ordering for javascript files, otherwise they are processed in order of AddFile calls
 var bootstrapOrdering = new BundleFileSetOrdering("bootstrap");

 //The popover plugin requires the tooltip plugin
 bootstrapOrdering.Files.Add("bootstrap-tooltip.js");
 bootstrapOrdering.Files.Add("bootstrap-popover.js");

 BundleTable.Bundles.FileSetOrderList.Add(bootstrapOrdering);
```

**UPDATE**
I reread your question and realized that you were surprised to see the jQuery comments on top.  This is due to a different reason than internal ordering:
Basically what happens is all comments on top of the files are extracted and merged together and put on top, this is for example for licensing reasons. Often you are not allowed to redistribute a library without a license on top of it and they usually are within the comments. This way the ASP.NET team made sure they are not omitted when minifying/bundling.

Comment: @IanDavis I updated the answer to reflect your actual question

Comment: you read it correctly.  I thought whatever order I added them to the bundle in global.asax was going to match whatever is rendered.  for instance, I need my jquery rendered first, THEN my test.js file. but, I'll try the bootstrap thing. thanks!

Comment: ps. how do I reference this in my layout.cshtml? `<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bootstrap")"></script>`

Comment: Anyone else? Just missing this last piece on how to actually reference it. Thanks.

Comment: @IanDavis As far as I understand this it changes the order in the  default bundle, if this does not work for you here is a detailed post on how to achieve what you want with a custom bundle: http://blog.decayingcode.com/post/2012/01/23/Javascript-and-CSS-MinifyingBundling-with-the-MicrosoftWebOptimization-Nuget-package.aspx